# Как сделать увеличение фигуры при клике на неё на 50px и уменьшение на 100px при достижении значения в 1000px HTML JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Суть задания:

- Вставьте блок шириной 100px.
- Курсор над блоком должен иметь вид "ладошки". Остальные стили подберите самостоятельно.
- Каждый щелчок по блоку должен приводить к увеличению ширины блока на 50px. Если ширина блока станет больше 1000px, то ширина должна сброситься обратно в 100px.

```js
function boom(div) {
  width = bodyInnerWidth + 'px';
  // let width = div.offsetWidth;
  if (width < '1000px') {
    div.style.width = `${width + 50}px`;
    // width += 50;
    // let h= width + 'px';
    // div.style.width = h;
  } else {
    div.style.width = '100px';
  }
}
```

```css
.block2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid;
  color: rgb(40, 7, 255);
  border-color: darkmagenta;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  /* margin: 10px auto; */
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="block2" onclick="boom(this)"></div>
```

Comment: Вам скорее нужен `JavaScript`, а не `Java`

Answer (score 2):

```js
function boom(div) {
  let bodyInnerWidth = div.offsetWidth + 50;
  if (bodyInnerWidth >= 1000) bodyInnerWidth = 100;
  div.style.width = bodyInnerWidth + 'px';
  div.textContent = bodyInnerWidth + 'px';
}
```

```css
.block2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid;
  color: rgb(40, 7, 255);
  border-color: darkmagenta;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  /* margin: 10px auto; */
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="block2" onclick="boom(this)"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо больше, код работает. Я в этом такой чайник поэтому простите если вопрос глупый. Вы на блок добавили надпись сколько пикселей. И вот при первом нажатии показывает 184px, а перед тем, как блок вернется к 100px стоит значение 940px и получается, что еще позволительно прибавить еще 50px. Просто не поняла почему так получается по моей логике должно быть по типу было 100+50=150px стала ширина и тд

Comment: @Виктория, из-за того, что у Вас отсутствует свойство `box-sizing: border-box`, все размеры _padding_ и _border_ **добавляются** к _width_. Итого: 940 (полученная ширина со всеми рамками и отступами) + 50 (инкремент) + 30 (отступы с обеих сторон) + 4 (рамка с обеих сторон) > 1000px.